# Selectively disable an Android service for certain API levels

Tags: android, android-manifest

My Android app supports API 8+, however the Parse library seems to break completely on APIs less than 10 (and even a little bit on 10 too). I know how to disable blocks of *code* on certain API levels, but is there a way that a `<service>` declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` can be selectively enabled only for API 11+? (it also gets started up by the `BOOT_COMPLETE` `<intent>` which would also need to be disabled)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step #1: Create a `res/values/bools.xml` file, with a `bool` resource named `i_can_haz_parse`, set to `false`

Step #2: Create a `res/values-v11/bools.xml` file, with a `bool` resource also named `i_can_haz_parse`, set to `true`

Step #3: Have `android:enabled="@bool/i_can_haz_parse"` on the components, like your service, that you want only on API Level 11+